# Data to Image conversion looks weird inside a Grid

Tags: swiftui, grid, mobile-development

I have a basic SwiftData model with `Images` stored as `Data`.
In my view I have those 2 variables:

```swift
@State private var selectedImages = [PhotosPickerItem]()
@State private var images = [Data]()
```

And in my view it looks like this:

```swift
let columns = [
    GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))
]

ScrollView {
    LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
        ForEach(images, id: \.self) { image in
            let uiImage = UIImage(data: image)
            Image(uiImage: uiImage!)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        }
    }
}
.padding(.horizontal)
```

But if you look at the picture below, the sizing only works for the second row. The first one looks super weird.

Can someone explain why?

[image: Image Bug]

Comment: because of `fill` likely you are telling the UI to fill the entire space regardless of the larger bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got.

I changed the `columns` to this:

```swift
let columns = [
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible()),        
    GridItem(.flexible())
]
```

And removed the `.aspectRatio` and gave the images a fixed height

```swift
ScrollView {
    LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
        ForEach(images, id: \.self) { image in
            let uiImage = UIImage(data: image)
            Image(uiImage: uiImage!)
                .resizable()
                .frame(height: 85)
        }
    }
}
.padding(.horizontal)
```

Now it looks better:
[image: Fixed Image Grid]